# Can be a random text content output (no text-area) be copied by using an input type button with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, copy

I'm trying to make a text encryptor page as my first developing challenge using HTML, CSS, and JS

**Task**

Make an `<input type="button">` copying a text output from a `<p>` that's displayed on the screen showing the result of the Encryption or Decryption of an input text written by the user in a `<textarea>`.

**Main problem**

I honestly don't know how to do it, and I've not found any question or reply about how to make the function of copying output text *outside of a `<textarea>`* giving this function to an *input button* through Javascript.

**Side problem**

I've actually used the `<button>` HTML tag but for the deleting button (the little red one displayed on the page) and it works, but at the cost of not applying its given CSS styles. I appreciate it if someone who knows why this happens tells me why.

**Things I tried**

I've been looking for options to do so but I've crossed paths with things I have no idea such as "`async", "navigation" or "exeCommand".  The point is I've tried some of these but most of the Internet examples I've found are using the HTML tag` `and not``, which is what my challenge asks me for.

**The Code**

```js
var botonEncriptador = document.querySelector(".btnEncrypt");
var botonDesencriptador = document.querySelector(".btnDesCrypt");
var botonCopiar = document.getElementById("copyButton");
var dollNotFound = document.querySelector(".msgMissDoll");
var msgNonExist = document.querySelector(".msgMissH2");
var inTxtEnDes = document.querySelector(".insertTxtEnDes");
var txtFinale = document.querySelector("#encryptResult");
botonEncriptador.onclick = funcionEncriptar;
botonDesencriptador.onclick = funcionDesencriptar;

function funcionEncriptar() {
  ocultarElementos();
  txtFinale.textContent = encriptarMensaje(recuperarContenido());
  //  Or:
  //  var area = recuperarContenido(); 
  //  txtFinale.textContent = encriptarMensaje(area);
  //P.D.: var "area" here is a local var of "funcionEncriptar", it is not the same one
  //from down there at "recuperarContenido" function.
}

function funcionDesencriptar() {
  ocultarElementos();
  txtFinale.textContent = desencriptarMensaje(recuperarContenido());
}

function borrarTextoArea() {
  document.getElementById("areaInput").value = "";
  //This function applies directly to the HTML button using the <button> tag.
}

function recuperarContenido() {
  var area = document.getElementById("areaInput");
  return area.value;
}

function ocultarElementos() {
  dollNotFound.classList.add("hideElement");
  msgNonExist.classList.add("hideElement");
  inTxtEnDes.classList.add("hideElement");
}

function encriptarMensaje(mensaje) {
  var textoIngresado = mensaje;
  var textoFinale = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textoIngresado.length; i++) {
    if (textoIngresado[i] == "a") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ai";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "e") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "enter";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "i") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "imes";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "o") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ober";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "u") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ufat";
    } else {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + textoIngresado[i];
    }
  }
  return textoFinale;
}

function desencriptarMensaje(mensaje) {
  var textoIngresado = mensaje;
  var textoFinale = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textoIngresado.length; i++) {
    if (textoIngresado[i] == "a") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "a";
      i = i + 1;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "e") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "e";
      i = i + 4;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "i") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "i";
      i = i + 3;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "o") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "o";
      i = i + 3;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "u") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "u";
      i = i + 3;
    } else {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + textoIngresado[i];
    }
  }
  return textoFinale;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  /*universal setting for no body margins*/
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  color: black;
  background-image: url("imgs/schoolclassjpgversion.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  /*Occupy the entire width of the page*/
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 250, 1.0);
}

.logoAluraHdr {
  padding-top: 5.5px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  /*background-color: rgb(185, 255, 92);*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background-color: rgb(101, 92, 228);*/
}

.sect1 {
  width: 70%;
}

#areaInput {
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  resize: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 253, 253, 0.754);
}

.encryptButtons {
  text-align: center;
}

.btnEncrypt,
.btnDesCrypt {
  width: 25%;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0A3871;
  transition: 2s all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnEncrypt:hover,
.btnDesCrypt:hover {
  border-color: #fff710;
  background: #3576c5;
}

.btnEncrypt:active,
.btnDesCrypt:active {
  background: #3ac7c5;
  transition: none;
}

.btnDeleTxt {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #ca1414;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.btnDelTxt:hover {
  background: #e33d3d;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/*From here the styles for the right section of the page begin*/

.sect2 {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.msgMissDoll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.msgMissH2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.insertTxtEnDes {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.encryptResCont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#secretMsgHdr {
  /*Default style of H2 didn't apply well, so I added this*/
  font-size: 24px !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.copyBtnCont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

#copyButton {
  width: 30%;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 250, 0.9);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.hideElement {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="newStyle.css">
  <title>Challenge Alura ONE #1 - Encriptor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="imgs/LogoOGLog.svg" alt="Small Alura's logo" class="logoAluraHdr">
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="sect1">
      <textarea id="areaInput" placeholder="Escríbeme por aquí"></textarea>
      <div class="encryptButtons">
        <input type="button" class="btnEncrypt" value="Encríptalo">
        <input type="button" class="btnDesCrypt" value="Desencríptalo">
      </div>
      <div id="deleteCont">
        <input type="button" class="btnDeleTxt" value="Borrar" onclick="javascript:borrarTextoArea();">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="sect2">
      <div class="msgMissDoll">
        <img src="imgs/MuñecologoDollAl.png" alt="Personaje animado lupa en mano no halla mensaje encriptado">
      </div>
      <div class="msgMissH2">
        <h2>Message not found</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="insertTxtEnDes">
        <p>Insert the text you want to Encrypt or Decrypt</p>
      </div>
      <div class="encryptResCont">
        <h2 id="secretMsgHdr">Secret message:</h2>
        <p id="encryptResult"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="copyBtnCont">
        <input type="button" id="copyButton" value="Copiar">
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p class="copyright">&copy Alura Latam - All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `addEventListener` to listen to the `click` event so when the button is clicked you can retrieve the text content of the encrypted result.

Try the following:

```
botonCopiar.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(txtFinale.textContent)
})
```

All the new JavaScript code would be:

```
var botonEncriptador = document.querySelector(".btnEncrypt");
var botonDesencriptador = document.querySelector(".btnDesCrypt");
var botonCopiar = document.getElementById("copyButton");
var dollNotFound = document.querySelector(".msgMissDoll");
var msgNonExist = document.querySelector(".msgMissH2");
var inTxtEnDes = document.querySelector(".insertTxtEnDes");
var txtFinale = document.querySelector("#encryptResult");
botonEncriptador.onclick = funcionEncriptar;
botonDesencriptador.onclick = funcionDesencriptar;

botonCopiar.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(txtFinale.textContent)
})

function funcionEncriptar() {
  ocultarElementos();
  txtFinale.textContent = encriptarMensaje(recuperarContenido());
  //  Or:
  //  var area = recuperarContenido(); 
  //  txtFinale.textContent = encriptarMensaje(area);
  //P.D.: var "area" here is a local var of "funcionEncriptar", it is not the same one
  //from down there at "recuperarContenido" function.
}

function funcionDesencriptar() {
  ocultarElementos();
  txtFinale.textContent = desencriptarMensaje(recuperarContenido());
}

function borrarTextoArea() {
  document.getElementById("areaInput").value = "";
  //This function applies directly to the HTML button using the <button> tag.
}

function recuperarContenido() {
  var area = document.getElementById("areaInput");
  return area.value;
}

function ocultarElementos() {
  dollNotFound.classList.add("hideElement");
  msgNonExist.classList.add("hideElement");
  inTxtEnDes.classList.add("hideElement");
}

function encriptarMensaje(mensaje) {
  var textoIngresado = mensaje;
  var textoFinale = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textoIngresado.length; i++) {
    if (textoIngresado[i] == "a") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ai";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "e") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "enter";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "i") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "imes";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "o") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ober";
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "u") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "ufat";
    } else {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + textoIngresado[i];
    }
  }
  return textoFinale;
}

function desencriptarMensaje(mensaje) {
  var textoIngresado = mensaje;
  var textoFinale = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < textoIngresado.length; i++) {
    if (textoIngresado[i] == "a") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "a";
      i = i + 1;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "e") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "e";
      i = i + 4;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "i") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "i";
      i = i + 3;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "o") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "o";
      i = i + 3;
    } else if (textoIngresado[i] == "u") {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + "u";
      i = i + 3;
    } else {
      textoFinale = textoFinale + textoIngresado[i];
    }
  }
  return textoFinale;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for responding this late. The addEventListener didn't work. It doesn't copy anything at all.